# How do I get the 'Instagram Public Content Access' Feature to work in my test app?

Tags: facebook, api, instagram

I want to create a [hashtag feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/) using the facebook API. I seem to be struggling with how I can allow the Feature 'Instagram Public Content Access' to work in my test app so I can do testing before submitting my app for review. I added a test user and it has basic_instagram permission but that is not enough to get a hashtag.

Do I need to add a user and assign a certain permission or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that you need to add the permission manage_pages along with instagram_basic and then you can do hashtag searches in your test app.